# Click button inside link

Tags: javascript

I have block with js action inside link block and I when user click with mouse on block with class `child_container` (see code bottom) then function `parent_link_trigger` is triggering. If I move element with class `child_container` outside, then a lot of logic is broken, so it takes a lot of time for refactoring. 
Here is my code:

```
<a class="parent_container" onclick="parent_link_trigger(); return false;" >
  <div><span>here some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child_container" onclick="children_link_trigger(); return false;">
  </div>
</a>
```

Is there any way to call child_container `onclick` listener, when mouse click on `child_container`?

Comment: Don't use inline events; they're much harder to work with. Register and manage your events centrally with `addEventListener()`. Your problem is happening because the inner event is 'propagating' to the parent event. Research stop event propagation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to stop the event from ***further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases*** using [`Event​.stop​Propagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the child function:

```js
function parent_link_trigger(){
  console.log('parent_link_trigger');
}
function children_link_trigger(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('children_link_trigger');
}
```

```html
<a class="parent_container" onclick="parent_link_trigger();" >
  <div><span>here some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child_container" onclick="children_link_trigger(event);">Child
  </div>
</a>
```